# Custom response in Express Validator

Tags: express, express-validator

I'm using Express Validator for my Rest API validation, here is my code in controller:

```
validate: function (method){
    switch (method) {
        case 'createPersonalInfo': {
            return [
                body('age').isInt().withMessage("Age should be integer")
            ]
        }
    }
},
```

it return response as :

```
{
    "status": 300,
    "messages": "Invalid Value",
    "param": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "value": "ABC",
                "msg": "Age should be integer",
                "param": "age",
                "location": "body"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I wanna custom the response, how to remove the field `"location:"`. Is it possible? I've been looking from many article but there's no one about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an error handler with express, and in this error handler, you can retrieve this error, modify it and return it.

You can retrieve the validation error in your route handler this way:

```js
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator/check')

app.get('/something', /* your validator middleware*/, function (req, res, next) {
  const errors = validationResult(req)
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    errors.throw()
  }
})
```

The error handler is defined at the end of your routing this way:

```js
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  let details = err.mapped && err.mapped()
  let errorsParam = []
  if (details) {
    for (let param of Object.keys(details)) {
      errorsParam.push({ param, msg: details[param].msg, value: details[param].value })
    }
  }
  res.status(400).json({ message: err.message, errors: errorParam })
})
```

Comment: Why do you suggest to do that in route? It's hard for me to do, because I define all routing in one file called index.js. It will contain thousand of line code if I have more than 50 routing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `validationResult().formatWith()` function to specify a formatter for your errors:

```
const result = validationResult(req).formatWith(({ msg, param, value }) => ({
  msg,
  param,
  value
}));
```

You can also create an instance of `validationResult()` that always uses the given formatter:

```
// Put it in a validation-result.js file somewhere in your project?
const myValidationResult = validationResult.withDefaults({
  formatter: ({ msg, param, value }) => ({
    msg,
    param,
    value
  })
});
const result = myValidationResult(req);
```

[Docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-result-api.html)